# A closed expression for definite integral of a rational function

Tags: integration, rational-functions

Suppose $F(x) = P(x)/Q(x)$ is an integrable rational function on $\mathbb R$, that is, $\deg Q \geq \deg P + 2$, and $Q$ has no real roots.

Does there exist an expression for the definite integral $I_F = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)dx$ in terms of only coefficients of $P$ and $Q$?

So far my idea was to apply the the residue theorem and the standard semicircle contour. This expresses $I_F$ as a symmetric function of *half* of all roots of $Q$, namely, those in the upper half-plane. Could we somehow upgrade it to a symmetric function of all of the roots, and thus the function of coefficients?

Comment: What sort of expression do you seek?  Since the integral already depends only on the coefficients, the question is just what kinds of expressions are allowed.

Comment: I think to get an "expression" for that integral, you would first need an "expression" for the complex zeros of the denominator?  Once you have the zeros of the denominator, you can do partial fractions (with complex coefficients).

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Of course, one could do it, but my hope was that we could avoid it somehow, and evaluate the integral *without* first finding zeroes of the denominator.

Comment: So you are essentially asking if you can express the roots in terms of the coefficients? By Abel-Ruffini, if $\operatorname{deg} Q\ge 5$, then there is no such expression as an algebraic function of the coefficients. There might be more complicated expression for the roots, however.

Comment: @Zachary, an algebraic function will almost never be possible: even in the simplest case, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx/(x^2+1)=\pi$

Comment: @MattF. I mean solely expressing the roots as an algebraic function of the coefficients. I did not say that the integral could be expressed this way. Of course by the residue theorem, you have a factor of $2\pi i$ that pops up, but modulo that factor, the residues are rational functions of the roots.